# How to rewrite lines in file?

Tags: text-processing, files, csv

In csv file couple of lines dont fit the data I need.
For example, this is my example.csv file:

```
14/Feb/2016:13:21:33-0500,mk
15/Feb/2016:14:21:33-0500,mk
16/Feb/2016:15:21:33-0500]http://map1.link.de/mk
17/Feb/2016:16:21:33-0500]http://map5.link.de/mk
```

I can fetch that lines and correct them with:

```
$ cat example.csv | grep "map" | sed 's/\(.*\)].*\/\(.*$\)/\1,\2/'
```

Result:

```
16/Feb/2016:15:21:33-0500,mk
17/Feb/2016:16:21:33-0500,mk
```

But what I really want is to correct them and save them like that in the same file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GNU Sed, just run:

```
sed -i '/map/s/\(.*\)].*\/\(.*$\)/\1,\2/' example.csv
```

**Warning:** This will overwrite the contents of the file.  Make a copy first if you're not sure the regex is *exactly* what you want.

---

If you *don't* have GNU Sed, or you just want a more portable solution that will run on any POSIX system, [use `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html):

For a trial run without editing the file:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/map/s/\].*\/\([^/]*\)$/,\1/' %p | ex example.csv
```

To save changes once you're happy with the result:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/map/s/\].*\/\([^/]*\)$/,\1/' x | ex example.csv
```